# How to generate hexadecimal pair for each byte and with leading zeroes

Tags: android

I am receiving a `string array` through the usb port and need to convert this to   `hexadecimal pairs` for each byte, separated by zero each pair and eading zeroes,

Using my code I get this:

```
41 54 2B 43 53 51 C A
```

But I need this:

```
41 54 2B 43 53 51 0C 0A
```

Here is my code:

```
  public class StringToHex {

    public String convertStringToHex(String str) {

        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

        StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            hex.append( Integer.toHexString( (int)  chars[i]).toUpperCase());
            if (hex.length() < 2) {
                hex.insert(1, '0');
            }
            hex.append(" ");
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }
}
```

but it does not work, what is the error?.

Comment: Please give an example. What is in the array? And how should it be displayed?

Comment: And there is no byte array in your code.

Comment: At the beginning I already updated my query

Comment: Do not directly append() but asign first to a String variable. If the size is 1 you can ad a "0" in front. After that append() the result.

Comment: For the rest you have no String array. There is no byte array. And i wonder why you would convert the chars of a string to hexadecimal notation. I wonder how you got that String from usb. It looks like the wrong approach.

Comment: blackapps,  
my code works and I can convert the data that I receive to hexadecimal, the inconvenience is that when I receive control data such as "\ n" and "\ r", I get the "C" and "A", but I need get "0C" and "0A", what changes do I have to make in the code to get that?

Comment: That i already told you